# Where to download XAMLPad?

Tags: wpf, xaml

If anyone know where to download XAMLPad? Or you know better alternative to test WPF?

Thanks

Comment: Does anybody know if is there an online version of this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To download XamlPadX v4 visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/xamlpadx-4-0) blog and you can find it as an attachment.

The **[WPF Test Tools](https://web.archive.org/web/20171225202452/http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=30923)** release will include tools for testing your WPF applications.

Comment: Go here for v4: http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/08/25/xamlpadx-4-0.aspx

Comment: Here's Lester's main XamlPadX page with all the versions: http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/pages/xamlpadx.aspx

Answer (score 12):

**XAML Editors**

The most popular XAML Editors.

- [XAML Pad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/xamlpadx-v2)
- [XAML PadX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/llobo/) (extended)
- XAML Hack
- KaXaml

Comment: KaXaml is really nice :)

Comment: I have used KAXAML and I can say it is better , with very less intricacies and simplicity

Comment: FYI: KaXaml cannot comment out code but it cleans up code very nicely. XamlpadX is now up to v4.0 but still cannot handle <DataGrid> tags

Comment: Just don't go to kaxaml home page .com, now it's owned by banners

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google revealed: [XAMLPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx)

It appears you need to install the Windows SDK: [Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en)